# Consulta pl/sql sobre diferencia de horas y minutos

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-11g

**Hola**,

Estimados tengo una duda existencia, lo que sucede es que tengo 2 campos string con horas en mi tabla, uno es el que da termino segun lo planificado y otro que en este caso seria la hora actual.

El **problema** no he podido realizar la comparacion con el dato de la hora de termino con la variable sysdate(hora actual) ya que solo estoy comparando horas y minutos.

Entonces he estado investigando y viendo como poder hacerlo y no me a resultado nada en pl/sql necesito una ayuda si me pudiesen guiar con una base como poder realizar la query seria de gran ayuda.

| Hora actual | Hora termino | Diferencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13:00 | 19:30 | +6:30 |

| Hora actual | Hora termino | Diferencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14:00 | 12:00 | -2:00 |

Si alguien tuviese conocimientos sobre esta query seria de gran ayuda muchas gracias :D

Comment: O sea, no podes restar dos fechas/horas?? ese es el problema?

Comment: Tal vez podrías usar [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_timestamp.php) para hacer la conversión del string y luego podrías intentar hacer la aritmética entre los tiempos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convierte a fechas.
2. Saca la diferencia y obtendrás horas.
3. Convierte la diferencia a segundos multiplicando por 24x60x60 (segundos en un día).
4. Convierte la diferencia a fecha usando `SSSSS` segundos.
5. Teniendo la fecha puedes reformatear a cadena con fecha y hora.

```
SELECT h.i
     , h.f
     , to_char( to_date( CASE
                           WHEN h.i < h.f 
                             THEN to_date(h.f,'HH24:MI') -to_date(h.i,'HH24:MI')
                           ELSE 
                             to_date(h.i,'HH24:MI') -to_date(h.f,'HH24:MI')
                         END
                       * 86400
                       ,'SSSSS'
                       )
             , CASE 
                 WHEN h.i < h.f THEN '+'
                 ELSE '-'
               END || 'HH24:MI'
             ) Diferencia
  FROM ( SELECT '13:00' i, '19:30' f FROM dual
         UNION
         SELECT '14:00', '12:00' f FROM dual
       ) h
```

Los `CASE` son para manejar el signo de la diferencia.

Comment: Excelente amigo esto es lo que realmente necesitaba y se ajusta perfectamente a mi requerimiento, muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es castear las cadenas con la hora y los minutos a tipo `time` y luego restarlos, el resultado será un intervalo con la diferencia:

```
-- Oracle 11g:
SELECT 
       hora_actual, 
       hora_termino, 
       CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(hora_termino, 'HH24:MI') AS time) - CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(hora_actual, 'HH24:MI') AS time) AS Diferencia
FROM t;

-- Oracle 18c:
SELECT 
       hora_actual, 
       hora_termino, 
       CAST(hora_termino AS time) - CAST(hora_actual AS time) AS Diferencia
FROM t;
```

La salida es:

| HORA_ACTUAL | HORA_TERMINO | DIFERENCIA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13:00 | 19:30 | +0 06:30:00 |
| 14:00 | 12:00 | -0 02:00:00 |

El formato de la diferencia no es exactamente el que vos querés, pero por ahí te sirve esta solución.